# Jenkins hangs when I try to run a container.inside() method

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

I've set up a pipeline, it's sole purpose is to build an image and then execute a simple command inside it.

I'm able to build the container, however, I'm not able to execute any commands inside of it. When I execute a 'sh' step, it just hangs indefinitely.

If I run a `container.run()` method or a `container.withRun`, the step executes but not actually inside the container.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here - could anybody advise the correct way to do this? I just want to be able to execute steps inside of the container, or alternatively - execute a command inside the container and then read the results of that operation back into Jenkins.

```
node {
    String baseName = "salimfadhley/python_hello_world_server"
    String buildTag = "${baseName}:${env.BUILD_ID}".toString()
    def customImage

    stage('Build') {
        checkout scm
        customImage = docker.build(buildTag)
    }

    stage('Test') {
        customImage.inside('--entrypoint=/bin/bash') {
            sh "pwd"
        }
    }

}
```

The Jenkins log output ends like this:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container ded46c77c61f36b31ea0cd8a067b20ebf97c71daa36c9c18a0c83d784f5791c5
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 --entrypoint=/bin/bash -w /var/jenkins_home/jobs/python-hello-world-server/branches/master/workspace --volumes-from ded46c77c61f36b31ea0cd8a067b20ebf97c71daa36c9c18a0c83d784f5791c5 -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** salimfadhley/python_hello_world_server:88 cat
$ docker top f5cd987963e5ea7c89cd70ddc6b2025d2bdab0ae1705c0b7a560fadc9aba0728 -eo pid,comm
ERROR: The container started but didn't run the expected command. Please double check your ENTRYPOINT does execute the command passed as docker run argument, as required by official docker images (see https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#consistency for entrypoint consistency requirements).
Alternatively you can force image entrypoint to be disabled by adding option `--entrypoint=''`.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Hello Inside!
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /var/jenkins_home/jobs/python-hello-world-server/branches/master/workspace@tmp/durable-50fcbb38
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 f5cd987963e5ea7c89cd70ddc6b2025d2bdab0ae1705c0b7a560fadc9aba0728
$ docker rm -f f5cd987963e5ea7c89cd70ddc6b2025d2bdab0ae1705c0b7a560fadc9aba0728
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM salimfadhley/testpython:latest
COPY . /project
COPY src /src
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN python -m pip install -e /project/src
WORKDIR /project
#ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "--port=80", "--host=0.0.0.0", "helloworld.main:app"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

So, to summarize: Can I fix this pipeline so that it actually allows me to run processes inside the container?

Comment: That `entrypoint` looks problematic.

Comment: It certainly is a problem - can you suggest how I might fix it? I need the entry point to be uvnicorn so that my image does what it's supposed to do when I docker-run it normally, but for Jenkins I need to be able to execute shell commands. That's why I thought I might override it in the container.inside command.

Comment: I would suggest removing it entirely for starters.

Comment: Do you mean remove the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile, or remove the --entrypoint switch in the Jenkinsfile? This image is based on the python:3.7 image which defines its entrypoint as a Python interpreter, so I expect that I need to override that at some time so that my scripts actually run.

Comment: Okay, looks like if you were right. If I clear out CMD, ENTRYPOINT and --entrypoint it works... but I do need to have the entrypoint set right in the thing I release. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I meant removing it in the Jenkinsfile. If this is an official python image (which it sounds like it is), then it very likely comes with a valid `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just running the dockerfile as an agent and run your stuff in steps.

```
stage {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      filename 'Dockerfile'
      reuseNode true // <- this is if you need to access the workspace
    }
  }
  steps {
    sh "run whatever stuff you want"
  }
}
```